# How to address encoding in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to parse quotes from a webpage using Ruby and Nokogiri and am running into issues. I believe it's an encoding issue but I'm not certain.

This is the code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open("https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/23218"))

tags = doc.css('div.quoteText')
a = tags[8].to_s
a = a.encode('iso-8859-1').force_encoding('utf-8')
# a = a.encode('cp1252').force_encoding('UTF-8')
puts ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(a[0,a.index('<br>')])
```

This is what gets returned:

```
  “â¦most of the damage we cause to the planet is the result of our own ignorance.”
```

I'm not sure how to get this to return the proper text...

```
“…most of the damage we cause to the planet is the result of our own ignorance.”
```

Any advice on how to get this to work properly? There are other examples of this happening from other quotes as well.

Comment: Try `Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open("..."), nil, "UTF-8")` to set the page's encoding to UTF-8 manually.

Comment: @engineersmnky interesting. I get `“â\u0080¦most` without specifying an encoding and `“…most` with `"UTF-8"`.